# grails run 'plugin' tests from 'app'

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

- I have a grails 'app' (say **myapp**) and a custom plugin (say **myplugin**) which are working together just fine.
- I have some 'integration' tests in myapp and I can run them just fine from the app by doing `cd myapp; grails test-app`
- I also have some 'integration' tests in **myplugin** and I can run them just fine from the plugin by doing `cd myplugin; grails test-app`

My problem is, that there does not seem to be any way to run **myplugin** test from **myapp**. E.g. what I'm trying to do is do a `cd myapp; grails test-app` to run *both* **myapp** and **myplugin** tests.

Is is even possible to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Plugin tests aren't distributed by default, and if they were (it's certainly possible to manually or automatically get them included in the zip) you shouldn't treat the plugin as a Grails plugin project, but rather an installable plugin. Pretend the plugin isn't source code but compiled classes. The fact that the files' extensions are .groovy, .gsp, .java, etc. should be considered a coincidence.

The plugin's BuildConfig.groovy is not included with the plugin zip, and this likely has important dependencies and/or other info needed to run anything in the plugin. To run the tests, run them from the plugin source directory.